# cloud firestore: set value without remove another value

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I use a model class to set data to Cloud Firestore.

```
public Users(String username,String age,String city,string avatar) {
        this.username = username;
        this.age=age;
        this.city=city
        this.avatar = avatar;
    }
```

And I want to set avatar first, another time I set username, age, and city. But when I set that the avatar value was removed.
I think I can try the update method but it needs a map and I want to use the model, I don't know have another way or I have to update the method.
Thanks for the help and have a nice day, everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you have a schema that looks like this:

```
Firestore- root
  |
  --- users (collection)
       |
       --- $uid (document)
            |
            --- username: "Lộc Trần Phước"
            |
            --- age: "20"
            |
            --- city: "Big City"
            |
            --- avatar: "https://..."
```

> and I want to set avatar first, another time I set username, age, and city.

If you want for example to change the value of avatar first, please use the following lines of code:

```
//Update avatar
Map<String, Object> updateAvatar = new HashMap<>();
updateAvatar.put("avatar", "otherURL");

String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference usersRef = rootRef.collection("users");
DocumentReference uidRef = usersRef.document(uid);
uidRef.update(updateAvatar).addOnCompleteListener(/* ... */);
```

In this way, you can update each field regardless of the others.

> I think I can try the update method but it needs a map and I want use model

If you want to update the avatar field, for example, using a model class, you need to read the content of the document first. Assuming you already have a `User` class, please use the following lines of code:

```
uidRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                User user = document.toObject(User.class);
                user.avatar = "otherURL";
                uidRef.set(user).addOnCompleteListener(/* ... */);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: it so detail. thank you so so much,have a good day!

Comment: You say *I think I can try the update method but it needs a map **and I want to use the model**.* So you are looking to update a document using a model class, and you accept an answer that provides an answer using a Map? It really might confuse future visitors.

Comment: i just think i should flexible , if use map is a key should i do.

Comment: Yes, it would be more flexible if you'll use a Map. That's why I **also** added that solution in my answer. However, your question was using **a model class**.

Comment: i did it.can i ask you few question, i use method onSuccessListener for put data but i retrieve null array, some one tell me should use interface cause this method is async. but i dont know how, can you give me a doc? thanks so much

Comment: Without seeing the code, I cannot be much of a help. So please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68559612/getter-and-setter-not-work-when-use-onsuccesslistener

Comment: , i posted this one or two day ago, but i still can't resolve it

Comment: I'll take a look and if I'll know the answer, I'll write to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Map<Key, Value> to update just some values.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#kotlin+ktx

```
val city = hashMapOf(
        "name" to "Los Angeles",
        "state" to "CA",
        "country" to "USA"
)

db.collection("cities").document("LA")
        .set(city)
        .addOnSuccessListener { Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully written!") }
        .addOnFailureListener { e -> Log.w(TAG, "Error writing document", e) }
```

Comment: so if i create a constructor contain value i want set, is this same result?

Comment: Do you mean separate constructor? I don't think it's gonna work, because in this case default values should set, so you need to use hashMap :)

Comment: it so sad. but thanks so much for helping!

Comment: @LộcTrầnPhước It's **not** mandatory to only use a Map. You can use a model class as well, as explained in my answer below.